# Convert SQL query to csv using odbc

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I'm trying to get data from an off-site Miscrosoft SQL database using php's odbc connection, convert certain queries against it to arrays, and then turn those arrays into a csv that my cms can read and import. I'm able to succesfully conncect and return some results from the database, but my lack of php and SQL skills is killing me.

What I have right now, which is not much, but does what it's supposed to do:

```
    $result = odbc_tables($connect);

    $tables = array();

    while (odbc_fetch_row($result))
    {
        if(odbc_result($result,"TABLE_TYPE")=="TABLE")
        echo"<br>".odbc_result($result,"TABLE_NAME");

    }
```

Is there any clear resource on the web on how to do what I want to do? The official php documentation seems to be about the most unhelpful documentation ever. A basic example: I want to return the entries here into csv format. I can get them in array format:

```
$query = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM Communities"; 

    $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);

    if ( $result )
    {
        while ( ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) )
        {
            print_r($row);
        }
        odbc_free_result($result);
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Exec error: ' . odbc_errormsg();
    }

    odbc_close($conn);
```

Wish I had more, but I'm a bit lost on where to go next.

Comment: Check out[`fputcsv()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), and find [supported protocols and wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) that can be used in [`fopen()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: Did fputcsv work for you?  If not, you could always try implode?   $csvline=implode(",",$row); will produce CSV where you have put your print_r($row);

Comment: worked swimmingly. took a few attempts, but it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Using the tips, here's the working solution:

```
$theArray = array();

while ( ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) )
{
    array_push($theArray, $row);
}


$header = array('Name', 'Hours', 'Fees', 'Notes', 'ShortDescription', 'URL');

$fp = fopen('array.csv', 'w');

fputcsv($fp, $header);

foreach ($theArray as $lines) 
{

    fputcsv($fp, $lines);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just got done doing the exact project that you are asking about. I am running php 5.2 so you may be able to deal with the csv file more easily in a newer version. Here is my code:

```
<?php
// Uncomment this line for troubleshooting / if nothing displays
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$myServer = "GSRBI";
$myUser = "webuser";
$myPass = "Webuser1";
$myDB = "GSRBI";

$dbhandle = odbc_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
    or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

$return = odbc_exec($dbhandle, 'select * from GSRBI.dbo.BounceBackEmail');

$subscribers_array = array(); 
$db_row = '';
$arrayrow = 0;

while ( $db_row = odbc_fetch_array($return) )
{
    $arrayrow++;
    $array[] = array(

                        'card_num' => $db_row['PlayerAccountNumber']
                        ,'last_name' => ucfirst(strtolower($db_row['LastName']))
                        ,'first_name' => ucfirst(strtolower($db_row['FirstName']))
                        ,'email' =>  $db_row['EMailAddress']
                        ,'earned_on_date' => date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-1 days'))
                        ,'free_play' => $db_row['Offer1']
                        ,'valid_through_date' => date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+15 days'))

                    );
    }
echo print_r($arrayrow, true); ## display number of rows for sql array
echo " rows in ODBC ";

// Creates an array with GSR webteams contact info
    $array1[] = array( 

                        'card_num' => "123456789"
                        ,'last_name' => "GSRwebteam"
                        ,'first_name' => "GSRwebteam"
                        ,'email' => "webteam@something.com"
                        ,'earned_on_date' => date('m/d/Y', strtotime('-1 days'))
                        ,'free_play' => "9"
                        ,'valid_through_date' => date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+15 days'))
                    );

$result = array_merge((array)$array, (array)$array1); ## merge the two arrays together


// This will convert the array to csv format then save it
 ## Grab the first element to build the header
$arr = array_pop( $result );
$temp = array();
    foreach( $arr as $key => $data ) 
    {
        $temp[] = $key;
    }
$csv = implode( ',', $temp ) . "\n";
$csv .= to_csv_line( $arr ); ## Add the data from the first element
    foreach( $result as $arr ) ## Add the data for the rest
    {   
        $csv .= to_csv_line( $arr );
    }
//echo print_r($csv, true); ## Uncomment to test output1

$f = fopen('reports/bounceback-'.date('m-d-Y').'.csv', "w");  
fwrite($f, $csv);  
fclose($f);
Echo "The report has ran";

return $csv;
function to_csv_line( $result ) 
    {
    $temp = array();
        foreach( $result as $elt ) 
        {
            $temp[] = '' . addslashes( $elt ) . '';
        }
        $string = implode( ',', $temp ) . "\n";
    return $string;
    }
```